# draw a shape inside canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

im quite new in html5 canvas, and i got a script online quite nice, is great in drawing shapes on images and grabbing the coordinates. Im using it to create costume tags on photos. The only issue im having is in creating static shapes tags above the image, i dont want the current canvas that is being used in the page influences in the static ones (when i say static im saying for example coordenates of shapes that already exist in the current image.

working example:
https://jsbin.com/putumeqeki/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? What are you trying to do or to avoid?

Comment: Also, all relevant code should be included on Stack Overflow itself, not some third party website. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].